# Bootstrap template plugins are free or not

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3

I bought one bootstrap template which is included lot of jquery plugins. I checked those plugins in online which is costlier than my template.

In my template, i checked the license terms. They mentioned that "Plugins, Images, iCons, etc., used in this template is copyrighted to respective owners and it comes under their License."

What does it mean. Template cost inclusive of Plugins, images etc or i have to buy all the plugins officially.

Please anyone can clarify this. Thanks

Comment: If they are included in a commercial template, the author has most likely purchased an extended licence that allows re-distribution.

Comment: they included in the catergory of business & corporate.https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ross-multi-purpose-parallax-theme-WB0G51219

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Comment: I know this is off-topic. But somebody can help me instead of saying this is off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inclusive means it includes. If a developer has additional plugins/images/icons, etc as previously mentioned, they allow re-distribution. Plugins would need to be purchased only if you would like the upgrades for them (the developer most likely has purchased an extended license that allows them to package, but won't transfer buyer rights to you for those free upgrades).

As for copyright, that just basically tells you that the theme developer is not the copyright holder for those items and is held to their license agreements (such as re-distribution).

Comment: Thanks Aibrean. So no need to buy those plugins again. i can use without purchasing anything. right.

Comment: Right. You would only need to buy if there was an update for them that was essential (like if you needed to update WP core and they would only work with an upgrade). In the original environment you would be fine.